# External users are unable to access nginx web server on VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, webserver, nginx

**Issue**
I can only access my nginx web server internally. The web server is hosted on my virtual machine. The outside world can not access it. By internally I mean within my virtual machine and the host machine, but not from an external device, e.g. my smartphone which is not connected to wi-fi. I have configured the virtual machine network settings to use *Bridges Adapter*, and I have configured port forwarding in my router (see images below). I can access the webserver on the host machine using both the external- and internal IP. Router has been restarted after configuration.

**Goal**
I want the outside world to be able to access my webserver.

*Specifications*
Host OS: Windows 10
Virtualization software: VirtualBox (Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.3 LTS)
Web server on VM: Nginx

**VirtualBox Network configuration:**

```
Attached to: Bridged Adapter
Name: Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
Adapter Type: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM)
Promiscuous Mode: Allow All
```

**All Name options:**

```
Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter 2
```

**Network interfaces**
[image]

**Router - Port forwarding**

```
Status: ON | TCP | Port: 80 | External Host: <ip from checkmyip.com> | Internal Host: 192.168.0.100
```

**ipconfig from virtual machine**

```
mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::1070:8c81:f616:2b84  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:7c85:b26e:a007:cfd5  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 08:00:27:c5:6f:79  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 400  bytes 320675 (320.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 292  bytes 42926 (42.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 173  bytes 15040 (15.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 173  bytes 15040 (15.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**nginx configuration**

```
...
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name 192.168.0.100;
}
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your current port forwarding rule translates to `Forward all packets received with source IP address <My.Own.Public.IP> and port 80 to 192.168.0.100`. By specifying the source IP you allow incoming traffic from that IP address only.

Comment: Thanks. What should I enter in the External- and Internal IP field if not the one mentioned?

Comment: Internal & port are good. I don't know the solution so can't say how it should be done in this case, but you need to allow all IPs. My guess would be either leaving the External IP empty; or using `0.0.0.0`, `0.0.0.0/0` or `0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255`.

Comment: Leaving it empty works. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! I put it in as an answer, please accept it. That'll mark it as "containing solution" in future searches, and picks it up from the Unanswered -queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the source IP (External Host) in a port forwarding rule limits the access to that IP address only. Consequently port forwarding rule

```
Status: ON | TCP | Port: 80 | External Host: <ip from checkmyip.com> | Internal Host: 192.168.0.100
```

translates to

```
Forward all packets with source IP <MyOwnIPAddr> and port 80 to 192.168.0.100
```

Port forwarding rules are created on the firewall, and since it'll never receive new connections originating from its own IP address, it'll block them. How the source IP should be configured depends on the solution and I'd expect to find it in the firewall's documentation, but leaving it blank often works. If not one of these might:

- 0.0.0.0
- 0.0.0.0/0
- 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255

All of these are used in routing to refer to unknown / undefined IP address.